# export a cdrom iso image with targetcli

Tags: iscsi, live-cd

In tgtd on fedora linux it  is easy to export cdroms to iscsi.

But i do not find any documentation how to do this with targetcli and LIO.
The only examples I find are about creating file backends with new files, but what about existing cdrom image files, how can they be attached to LIO and exported with targetcli?

Comment: What Linux distro do you use?

Comment: i use fedora 25 on a arm machine